# I'm tryin to replace external website with localhost via modem settings

Tags: networking

I need to replace real external url website with my localhost website like 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.24. I want to do this with my modem settings. I need to manipulate a real domain name is like http://smarttv.website.com/TV with my localhost. If I enter the http://smarttv.website.com/TV website I need to see my localhost website content. How can I do that with my modem settings. Or anybody know any different solution?

Modem : Huawei HG255s OS : Windows 10

If I manipulate real domain name I can run my website on TV.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to inject a static DNS entry into the lookup table of the DNS server running in the Huawei device.

The device you referenced is actually a device that combines many features like routing, modem, DNS, DHCP, NAT etc. This is beneficial in your case because you may have a chance to add a DNS entry in the DNS server. If that is not possible, you can set up a DNS server running in your LAN and have that served as the DNS server of your network by using that in the DHCP config. Then, you can add the entry there. For the actual DNS server, I recommend something like pi-hole since it was specifically developed for such purposes.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find out whether your device supports such a DNS injection. However, reconfiguring the DNS server in the DHCP config is usually supported by consumer-grade hardware.

There is one big caveat to keep in mind; if that external site is request with HTTPS by your TV this approach might not work since you won't be able to provide the necessary SSL certificate.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for this beaufly answer.